# How to use a variable as a table name in OleDbAdapter

Tags: vb.net, variables, oledbdataadapter

I have a database "NBCDB.accdb" which consist of 5+ tables
tablesnames are "Brgy,Citymun,GenClass, etc."
how to use a variable tablename inside oledbadaptor 
("Select * from variabletablename")
i want to change the tablename based on what my combobox is selected

Thanks.

here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmbCity_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbCity.SelectedIndexChanged

    Brgytxt = cmbCity.Text
    myConnToAccess = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=NBCDB.accdb")
    myConnToAccess.Open()
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from Brgy", myConnToAccess)
    da.Fill(ds, "Brgy")
    With ComboBox13
        .DataSource = ds.Tables("Brgy")
        .DisplayMember = Brgytxt
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With
    TextBox9.Text = Brgytxt
End Sub
```

Comment: `"Select * from " & tablenameVariable`

Comment: Thanks Tim, it passed but gave me "Could not find file" at da.Fill(ds,Brgytxt). can this line also accept variable? TIA

Comment: Update your question and add the exact code you tried...

Answer (score 0):

Please Check below source code, I have edited from your source code

Private Sub cmbCity_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbCity.SelectedIndexChanged

```
Brgytxt = cmbCity.Text
myConnToAccess = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=NBCDB.accdb")
myConnToAccess.Open()
ds = New DataSet
tables = ds.Tables
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from " & cmbCity.Text", myConnToAccess)
da.Fill(ds, "Brgy")
With ComboBox13
    .DataSource = ds.Tables(cmbCity.Text)
    .DisplayMember = Brgytxt
    .SelectedIndex = -1
End With
TextBox9.Text = Brgytxt
```

End Sub

Hope, It will be useful for you.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Mashesh, but the code you edited gave me this warning "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to system.data.ole.oledbcommand"

Comment: Can you send me snap-shot of warning?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim and Mahesh.

here's what i've done so far which gives me the error message.

[warning/error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WHYX.jpg)

Private Sub cmbCity_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbCity.SelectedIndexChanged

```
    Brgytxt = cmbCity.Text
    myConnToAccess = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=NBCDB.accdb")
    myConnToAccess.Open()
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from " & Brgytxt, myConnToAccess)
    da.Fill(ds, Brgytxt)
    With ComboBox13
        .DataSource = ds.Tables(Brgytxt)
        .DisplayMember = Brgytxt
        .SelectedIndex = -1
    End With
    TextBox9.Text = Brgytxt
End Sub
```

da.Fill(ds.Brgytext) <-- can this line also accepts variable? (i have a table named whatever Brgytext or cmbCity.text contains.)
TIA